# Unable to find instrumentation target package firebase error

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, automated-tests

I'm writing an instrumentation test for my app in a separated empty project using UIAutomator and AndroidJUnit4 as runner. It runs well on my device. For testing it on Firebase, it needs the application APK which I provided, and the test APK which I took from C:\Users\user\MyApplication\app\build\outputs\apk\androidTest\debug and when I run the test it fails with this error:"Unable to find instrumentation target package:" am I missing something?

I created another manifest into the androidTest package and the target package is red with "cannot resolve symbol" and nothing changed.

I also changed the targetPackage to the name of the package of the application I'm trying to test, in case that was the problem, and nothing changed.

My androidTest manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapplication.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="28"/>


    <instrumentation
        android:targetPackage="com.example.myapplication"
        android:name="androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        />

    <application
        tools:replace="label" android:label="SampleTest"/>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found out that gradle changes the target package automatically to the application package name which I'm writing test on.
So I had to move my tests to my application project and generate test apk from it, so it will have the same target package while setting the same signature for both.